# SwiftUI - API - problem with data download

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am a novice SwiftUI developer. I am trying to get data via the API of my wordpress website.

API link: https://amatorkamp.pl/wp-json/sportspress/v2/tables

I don't understand how I can join the DATA structure. If I want to download data from the first structure (ID, SLUG), everything works fine for me, but if I try to download data from DATA (PTS, NAME, POS), we have no data.

```
import Foundation
struct TaskEntry: Decodable  {
var pos: Int
var name: String 
}
```

--

```
import SwiftUI


struct ContentView: View {
@State var results = [TaskEntry]()

var body: some View {
    List(results, id: \.id) { item in
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            //Text(item.slug)
            Text(item.name)
            //Text(item.rendered)
        }
    }.onAppear(perform: loadData)
}


func loadData() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://amatorkamp.pl/wp-json/sportspress/v2/tables") else {
        print("Your API end point is Invalid")
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        if let data = data {
            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode([TaskEntry].self, from: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.results = response
                }
                return
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

Comment: Is `self.results = response` called? If not, why did you write `try?`, and not a `do`/`try`/`catch`? Because it's not repeated enough but NEVER use `try?` (with question mark) unless you know how do debug it. Use `do`/`try`/`catch` and print the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is not right, so you can't decode it. So please rethin your model. I checked your api call quick, and pos in nested inside the data object, you could use a site like quickType.io, so create the right model corresponding to your data.

Like to site: app.quicktype.io.